# How can I design the query to properly select from the database

Tags: php, sql

The way I try to select:
`SELECT * FROM products_translate WHERE (category IN(10)) AND .....`

The contents of the field in the database:
category - 7, 10

This structured query only shows products that are only categorized by category 10 but not those that contain another category. 
For example 7, 10

How can I properly structure the query?

Database structure:

```
TABLE `products_translate` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uniqueID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
```

Accordingly, the category field may contain:
`(1, 3, 7, 10)`

One of the records in the database
`(109, 109, 'title', '7, 10')`

My purpose is to select 7, 10 database requests to output all the entries they contain in the category 7 or 10 field.

Comment: This happen because you select all category that is equal to 10.

Comment: Why you don't add 7 in your IN, like `SELECT * FROM products_translate WHERE (category IN(10, 7)) AND`

Comment: Exactly how the data is recorded in category field ? Seems it is text field with numbers delimited by comma

Comment: Did you write this query? If so, did you have any reason to put `category in(10)` in your query?

Comment: What is the logic given that 10 is contained in 7, 10 i send and 7 in the query?

Comment: @Nima 
Yes, because I can also select more categories. For example, 1,7,9 and the request becomes something of the sort of `SELECT * FROM products_translate WHERE ( category IN(7, 10))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do `SELECT * FROM products_translate WHERE (category IN(10)) AND .....` you will only return row with `category = 10`.

So you can do :

- `SELECT * FROM products_translate WHERE (category < 10) AND ...` : if you want category 1, 2, 3 ... 10
- `SELECT * FROM products_translate WHERE (category IN(7, 10)) AND ...` : if you want category 7 and 10 only
- `SELECT * FROM products_translate WHERE ... GROUP BY category` : to return all element (according to you WHERE condition) but group by `category`(one element of each)
- `SELECT * FROM products_translate WHERE ... ORDER BY category` : this way you will have your return elements order by `category`

Is it what you are looking for ?

EDIT : after you added some information about your table structure

`SELECT * FROM products_translate WHERE (category LIKE '%10%') AND ...` : this will select row where "10" is present in category field. But becareful, it will works with category like `105` or `810` too

Your category field is a bad idea : using a VARCHAR to put multiple category in one field is not very efficient...it should be an INTEGER and so for element with category 7 and 10 you should have 2 element in your table and not one. For this add UNIQUE INDEX on uniqueID + categoryID to avoid duplicate.

Comment: Hi, Mickaël Leger try to select all entries that contain 10 in the category field

Comment: If you want entries that contain 10 then you want `...WHERE category = 10` ? We don't know how you table looks like and what's inside so hard to know if category is unique or entries can have multiple category

Comment: Entries can have multiple categories in the field that I select 7, 10

Comment: You should edit your question to show your database structure, it's hard to answer like this because `WHERE category = 10` will do the job by returning element with category 10. Maybe you need a subquery that could look like this `WHERE id_products = (SELECT id_product FROM products_translate WHERE category = 10)` but can't tell without more details

Comment: I added more information. If there is something I miss, say to add it. Thank you !

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I'm looking for! 
This, in my opinion, is the right way to communicate, not just like the other haters they know a lot!

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET()` if your db is mysql

```
 SELECT * FROM products_translate WHERE FIND_IN_SET('7, 10',category)> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

To query for category that is equal to 7 or 10 you just need to add 7 in your query.

```
SELECT * FROM products_translate WHERE category IN (10, 7)
```